# How to group dates and associated state

Tags: c#, linq

So I have the following data:

```
State  Date
AK     11/27/2014   
AL     11/27/2014
HI     11/30/2014
```

I want to have the data displayed on a webpage like this:

```
State    Date
AK, AL   11/27/2014
HI       11/30/2014
```

I am using Linq to get back a comma separated list of states, and a comma separated list of dates.

But these are just assigned to 2 separate strings

Here is what I am using:

```
State = Version.States
               .Aggregate(string.Empty, (c, state) =>
                   c + state.CountryState.State.StateShortName.ToString() + ", ")
                            .TrimEnd(',', ' '),
StartDate = Version.States
                   .Aggregate(string.Empty, (c, date) =>
                       c + date.StartDate.Date.ToShortDateString() + "," + System.Environment.NewLine)
                               .TrimEnd(',', ' ')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy:-

```
var result = states.GroupBy(x => x.Date)
                   .Select(x => new { State = String.Join(",",x.Select(z => z.State)), 
                                              Date = x.Key.ToShortDateString() });
```

Working [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/i0hmKG).

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
var result = data.GroupBy(x=>x.Date)
                 .Select(x=>new {
                     Date = x.Key.ToShortDateString(),
                     Satet = String.Join(",",x.Select(y=>y.State))
            });
```

where `data` holds all your data in the form you posted.

Answer (score 0):

I would tend to group the data first, on the common dates, before projecting out the combined states. Also, `String.Join` is generally an easier way to fold over strings than the more general `.Aggregate`. You didn't post the full hierarchy, but here's a solution on a simplified model:

```
public class StateVersion
{
    public string StateShortName;
    public DateTime Date;
}

var stateVersions = new List<StateVersion>
{
    new StateVersion { StateShortName = "AK", Date = new DateTime(2014, 11, 27)},
    new StateVersion { StateShortName = "AL", Date = new DateTime(2014, 11, 27)},
    new StateVersion { StateShortName = "HI", Date = new DateTime(2014, 11, 30)}
};

var aggStates = stateVersions.GroupBy(sv => sv.Date.ToShortDateString())
    .Select(g => String.Join(",", g.Select(x => x.StateShortName)) + " " + g.Key)
    .ToList();

foreach (var s in aggStates)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(s);
}
```

[IdeOne Fiddle](http://ideone.com/fS4iQn)

Comment: Get this when output to screenL System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.String,VersionState],System.String]